# Pushing info from a form into one of several JS arrays based on class names

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

**I'm trying to sort data taken from a form and insert it into different arrays based on class assignments in the form.** I am new to jquery and JS so this could be totally off base but here's what I'm trying to do:

```
<input type="text" id="word1" class="noun">Noun
```

and the scripts:

```
var noun = [];

// code that cycles through the form cut out.....

// here is the trouble spot:

var thing = $(this).val();
var whichArray = $(this).attr('class');

whichArray.push(thing);
```

Now if `console.log` the values everything looks good - I get the right info in both thing and whichArray but that `push()` command doesn't work.

Comment: Strings don't have the method `push`. `.attr("class")` returns a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that whichArray is a String, not an Array. You need to actually retrieve the array named whichArray. So you could modify your code thus:

```
var arrays = {};
arrays["noun"] = noun;

// your code here, then:

arrays[whichArray].push(thing);
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I feel like an idiot about this one. :D It's working now.